# Seeking story with a guessing game with a man and an angel

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to locate a humorous story that I have never actually *read* myself.  Rather, I heard part of it read aloud at a speech and debate tournament in high school.  That was in 1993, but I suspect the selection was quite a bit older.

The piece, which I recall was stated to be an excerpt from a longer work, involved an angel visiting a mortal man.  The man is trying to guess who the mysterious visitor is.  The angel had displayed some kind of weird abilities that got the man curious.  What I really remember clearly though was the guessing game, where the angel was giving the man "hot" and "cold" clues.  Whenever the man mentioned "God," the angel got very excited and described how very hot the man's guesses were.  (The guy doing the reading was particularly emotive and hilarious on this point, which led to him winning the tournament.)

Eventually, the man guesses that the angel is actually God, and the angel says, effectively:  *No, but I'm a good friend of his.*  That's when the reading ended, so that's all I know.